# Handling Multiple Values in One Cell to Export To CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to design a VBA script that will export values from an Excel spreadsheet to a CSV file. This will be used for deployment of multiple Virtual Machines by a separate Powershell script.

Currently the Export to CSV operation is handling one single VM name per cell and the corresponding settings however, in the actual execution of the script we may have multiple VM names in a single cell (separated by a comma) but will have the same settings in the proceeding cells.

What I would like to know is whether it is possible/how to go about having those values in that cell that are separated by a comma populate a separate line but still have the settings under the appropriate headings within the CSV file.

The code:

```
Function BuildValuesString(colIndex As String, rows As String) As String
    Dim val As Variant

    For Each val In Split(rows, ",")
        If Cells(val, colIndex) <> "" Then BuildValuesString = BuildValuesString & Cells(val, colIndex).Value & ","
    Next val
End Function
Function BuildNullStrings(numNullStrings As Long) As String
    Dim iNullStrings As Long

    For iNullStrings = 1 To numNullStrings
        BuildNullStrings = BuildNullStrings & "" & ","
    Next iNullStrings
End Function


Sub WriteCSVFile2()

    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim logSTR As String

    My_filenumber = FreeFile

    logSTR = logSTR & "Srv. Descr." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "E-mail" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Env." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Prot. Level" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "DataC" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "# VMs" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Name" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Cluster" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "VLAN" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "NumCPU" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "MemoryGB" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "C_System" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "D_Homevg" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "App_eHealth" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "TotalDisk" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Datastore" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Template" & ","

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34")
    logSTR = logSTR & TotalIt(Range("C32:C33"))

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildNullStrings(5)
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,46")
    logSTR = logSTR & TotalIt(Range("C43:C44"))

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildNullStrings(5)
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,58")
    logSTR = logSTR & TotalIt(Range("C54:C55"))

Open "Z:\Operational Env. Requests\2016\Requests(Test)\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub

Function TotalIt(rng As Range)
    Dim c, arr, t, rv As Double, v
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(c.Value, ",")
            For Each v In arr
                If IsNumeric(v) Then rv = rv + v
            Next v
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    TotalIt = rv
End Function
```

I.E. 
If cell C:27 has "VM1, VM2, VM3", separate each value on a different line but still input values associated with the other headers.

Currently the VBA script would input the values as:

```
Name           Cluster     VLAN   NumCPU      MemoryGB
VM1             VM2         VM3   VMCluster   VLAN1 etc.
```

What I would like it to do is

```
Name  Cluster    VLAN
VM1   VMCluster  VLAN1
VM2   VMCluster  VLAN1
VM3   VMCluster  VLAN1
```

It messes up the alignment completely if I attempt to execute the VBA script in its current format. I was hoping to get some help on how I could go about achieving the desired results.

Thank you for any assistance you may provide

Comment: Hi, have a look at a [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) - *"Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings."*. You can apply this to C27, then check how many substrings it returned. Modify your macro accordingly.

Comment: you should also look at InStr to check for the comma first and create your logic for if it is found or not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: FWIW - Your `BuildNullStrings(5)` can be replaced with `String(5, ",")`, getting rid of the need for the function.  (Or, if you prefer, change the contents of `BuildNullStrings` to simply say `BuildNullStrings = String(numNullStrings, ",")` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is radically oversimplified, but based on your simplified example of Name, Cluster and VLAN in columns A-C, this would take that and split the output to a CSV.

```
Sub SplitToCsv()

  Dim rw, lastRow As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim vms, vm, rowData As Variant

  Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
  lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Open "C:\test.csv" For Output As #1

  For rw = 1 To lastRow
    vms = Split(ws.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, ",")
    For Each vm In vms
      Print #1, Join(Array(vm, ws.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, ws.Cells(rw, 3).Value2), ",")
    Next vm
  Next rw

  Close #1

End Sub
```

This would take this as an input:

```
Name          Cluster     VLAN
VM1,VM2,VM3   VMCluster   VLAN1
VM4           VMCluster2  VLAN2
VM5,VM6       VMCluster3  VLAN3
```

And turn it into a file that looks like this:

```
Name,Cluster,VLAN
VM1,VMCluster,VLAN1
VM2,VMCluster,VLAN1
VM3,VMCluster,VLAN1
VM4,VMCluster2,VLAN2
VM5,VMCluster3,VLAN3
VM6,VMCluster3,VLAN3
```

-- EDIT 1/3/2017 --

I think I get it now.  This is a slimmed-down / refactored version of your code.  I could be wrong, but I **believe** this is what you're trying to do:

```
Sub WriteCSVFile2()

    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim header, line As String
    Dim values, vlan, names As Variant
    Dim row As Integer

    My_filenumber = FreeFile
    Open "c:\cdh\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, Join(Array("Srv. Descr.", "E-mail", "Env.", _
        "Prot. Level", "DataC", "# VMs", "Name", "Cluster", "VLAN", _
        "NumCPU", "MemoryGB", "C_System", "D_Homevg", "App_eHealth", _
        "TotalDisk", "Datastore", "Template"), ",")

    header = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("C18:C22").Value), ",")

    For row = 26 To 50 Step 12
      values = Application.Transpose(Range("C" & row & ":C" & row + 8).Value)
      names = values(2)
      For Each vlan In Split(names, ",")
        values(2) = vlan
        line = Join(values, ",")
        Print #My_filenumber, header & "," & line
      Next vlan
    Next row

    ' TotalIt(Range("C54:C55"))

    Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

Some notes:
 - I commented out `TotalIt` just because I assume it works and wasn't focused on that part
 - Your code looked at rows 26, 37, 48 but the spreadsheet actually had the references at 26, 38, 50 (one additional row).  My code reflects the latter

I think the smaller code base will be easier to debug and hopefully more scalable, if you ever add more config options.

Here is my output:

```
Srv. Descr.,E-mail,Env.,Prot. Level,DataC,# VMs,Name,Cluster,VLAN,...
Service,Email,Environment,Protection,Data Center,,VM1,VMCluster,VLAN1 etc.,,,,,
Service,Email,Environment,Protection,Data Center,,VM2,VMCluster,VLAN1 etc.,,,,,
Service,Email,Environment,Protection,Data Center,,VM3,VMCluster,VLAN1 etc.,,,,,
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - because I am extracting this data from an Excel spreadsheet and exporting it to the CSV file, all of the 'Name', 'Cluster', 'VLAN', etc. data is coming from the C column (in a single cell, C:27). Is there a way to specify that within the solution you provided? Name, Cluster and VLAN end up being in 3 separate columns within the CSV only after they have been exported

Comment: Any chance you can upload a copy of the spreadsheet so I can see it in living color?

Comment: I think I understand now...  I also understand why I didn't at first glance understand what your code was doing.  Now it makes sense.  I just posted an update which I hope will be dramatically simplified.  Let me know if it's not working or doesn't make sense

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for looking at that and coming up with such a clean solution. I am now getting the desired results. Would you happen to know if there is a way to modify this code to have it 'ignore' blank cells? The data in each configuration section in cells C32:C33, C44:C45 and C56:C57 will ever only have one or the other filled in - as such, the data will still fall under the same headers (C_system, D_Homevg, App_eHealth). Currently if the latter of the two cells is filled in, it leaves a blank cell under C_System and shifts the data over by one column

Comment: Is it safe to say it will always contain one and only one of those three values, and all other values will never be blank?  My fear of removing any blank is the risk that the number of fields will be different, but you would know if that's possible or not.

Comment: There will always be one numerical value under each one of those 3 columns and the cell from the Excel spreadsheet will always contain 3 values.

Comment: Hmm...  okay, well as you can imagine, this is certainly possible, but the compact nature of the code is in jeopardy if we have to selectively remove a null out of one of those two columns.  quick question -- where is this CSV file going -- to a database, by any chance?  If so, can you coalesce the two fields on output?  If not, can we manufacture a third field which does the coalescing -- essentially add one column to your CSV, and the result is the "Requirements," whether Win or Linux?

Comment: The CSV file gets placed on a local drive, no database unfortunately. Would adding a third field put all of the data from that cell within that new third field? The Powershell script I am running to create the VMs is pulling the hard disk size from each individual columns so I am not sure if that would complicate that function: The cmdlet that is used within the Powershell for each column is Set-HardDisk -HardDisk Disk 1 -CapacityGB  $_.C_System (for each individual hard disk if that helps make more sense of what I am trying to do)

Comment: So to allow for that null cell, would I re-add the function that was included in my original code? I think that was what was allowing the null values previously: `Function BuildNullStrings(numNullStrings As Long) As String
    Dim iNullStrings As Long

    For iNullStrings = 1 To numNullStrings
        BuildNullStrings = BuildNullStrings & "" & ","
    Next iNullStrings
End Function`